# jquery popout of details on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery

On [Google News](http://news.google.com/). there is a carousel with a popout on mouseover on an item.  I've also found a video with a tutorial of how to make one: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iy78nJgRiUM

Can anyone suggest some other (better?) tutorials out there on how to achieve the same effect?

I'm really looking for this exact behaviour.  I'm not really looking to use tooltips, title/alt tags, modal windows, etc.

Edit: Don't you hate it, when you post a question you find somewhere?  Ok, I found this also, which will probably help me out.  But I am still interested in what others might add. :)

http://impact-products.co.uk/category.asp?cat=Sound

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I took what was in http://impact-products.co.uk/category.asp?cat=Sound and used it for my own purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just do something like this:

```
$(".myElement").hover(function() { // mouseover
    // add and show a div styled with css
}, function() { // mouseout
    // remove the div
});
```

Its simple, allows you to display any content you want (in the div), and is customizable (using css).  You may also try using jQuery UI's modal as the popup, but I think that'd be too much.